# Android: Camera App Crushed because camera being accessed too many times

Tags: android, multithreading, camera

I have a camera app that takes pictures when user clicks a button. Every time when user clicks the button I will disable the button and then enable the button after the picture has been saved to the phone.

This enable and disable stuff is done to prevent user striking the button crazily and destroy the app. However, it seems like it is not working as I expected. Any suggestion why this is happening? I am guessing multiple threads are trying to enable and disable the button at the same time, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: We need more information.
How are you calling the camera? What are the errors? Logcat? Code?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a concurrency problem. And I solved this by using ReaderWriterLockSlim to enable and disable the button which have solved problem (I was developing in Monodroid).